# Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I use `PhoneGap` for `Android`

I have some inputs... by clicking on one of them I open a div on all screen (the **same** div) by clicking on the two input everything is normal, but in the third appears to me the following error message in console:

```
Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen
```

What does this mean? **It gives me problems on overriding the back button** ..

Full log output:(When click on input with problem)

```
01-15 15:13:40.360: D/navcache(2231): cursorInputFieldAction cursor=8ef220, cursorFrame=a8cf78
01-15 15:13:40.360: D/navcache(2231): CachedFrame::previousInputField this=a8cf78, start=8ef220, begin=8eee38 end=8ef540
01-15 15:13:40.360: D/navcache(2231): CachedFrame::nextInputField this=a8cf78, start=8ef220, begin=8eee38 end=8ef540
01-15 15:13:40.360: D/navcache(2231): cursorInputFieldAction next=8ef284, prev=0, action=4
01-15 15:13:40.372: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
01-15 15:13:40.563: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
01-15 15:13:40.778: V/webview(2231): OnSizeChanged: Enter 
01-15 15:13:41.336: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
01-15 15:13:41.336: E/webtextview(2231): ....Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen....
```

Full log output:(When click on input without problem)

```
01-15 15:17:29.813: D/navcache(2231): cursorInputFieldAction cursor=6ac13c, cursorFrame=81aba0
01-15 15:17:29.813: D/navcache(2231): CachedFrame::previousInputField this=81aba0, start=6ac13c, begin=6abcf0 end=6ac3f8
01-15 15:17:29.813: D/navcache(2231): CachedFrame::nextInputField this=81aba0, start=6ac13c, begin=6abcf0 end=6ac3f8
01-15 15:17:29.813: D/navcache(2231): cursorInputFieldAction next=6ac1a0, prev=6ac0d8, action=5
01-15 15:17:29.836: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
01-15 15:17:30.196: V/webview(2231): OnSizeChanged: Enter 
01-15 15:17:30.598: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
01-15 15:17:30.598: I/dalvikvm(2231): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
01-15 15:17:30.680: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2231): Ignore this event
```

the Error input:

```
  <input onkeydown="X();" onclick="OpenOnScreen();" oninput="XXX();" type="text"  id="ErrorInp"  />
```

the Good input:

```
  <input onkeydown="X();" onclick="OpenOnScreen();" oninput="XXX();"  type="text" id="GoodInp" />
```

the DIV that open on all screen:

```
<div id="OpenDiv">
           ...
        </div>
```

Style:

```
#OpenDiv
{
    background-color: yellowGreen;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 7000;
    display: none;
}
```

Function OpenOnScreen:

```
function OpenOnScreen() {
    $('#OpenDiv').css('display', 'block');
}
```

When I define the height of the div to 80% I do not get this error message and the back button works, why is this happening? (I need its height will be 100%)

Comment: Can you provide us with a full log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output is not an error. It is just a request for a rectangle of this view be visible on the screen. A View should call this if it maintains some notion of which part of its content is interesting. For example, a text editing view should call this when its cursor moves.

I would guess, can't tell you why (I cant't see your code) phonegap is accessing a rectangle **Rect** object in the current **View**. So just disregard this, this is just a background java notification.

I can't see any real error in this output thus I would assume your problem is on the javascript side.

Comment: But I open the same div, from several different Inputs and in others there is no this error .. This causes problems for me on the back button, I override him to trigger a specific function, and Input with the problem is ignored overrides and the app closes instead

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that this is not an error you are looking for.

Comment: It is what I was looking for! Because when there is no this error the back button running my function